# How to define the protobuf-net model with a generic base class?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Given these types:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class EntityId
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string IdAsString { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2), XmlIgnore]
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    #region XML hacks

    [XmlElement("Type"), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string AssemblyQualifiedTypeName
    {
      get { return ValueConverter.Default.Type2String(Type); }
      set { Type = ValueConverter.Default.String2Type(value); }
    }

    #endregion
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class EntityRelation
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Path { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Base<TId>
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public TId Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public EntityId ParentId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public int LastChanged { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public EntityRelation EntityRelation { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class FlowFolder : Base<int>
  {
  }
```

This model definition:

```
  var m = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
  m.AutoCompile = false;
  m.Add(typeof(Base<int>), true).AddSubType(1, typeof(FlowFolder));
```

And this usage:

```
var entity = GetFlowFolder();
var typeTag = GetTypeTag(entity);
Model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, entity, null, PrefixStyle.Base128, typeTag);
```

I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=Duplicate field-number detected; 1 on: NC.DTO.Base`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
  Source=protobuf-net
  StackTrace:
       at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer..ctor(Type forType, Int32[] fieldNumbers, IProtoSerializer[] serializers, MethodInfo[] baseCtorCallbacks, Boolean isRootType, Boolean useConstructor, CallbackSet callbacks, Type constructType) in z:\Work\protobuf-net-v2\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 43
  InnerException:
```

With the following stack trace:

```
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.TypeSerializer(System.Type forType, int[] fieldNumbers, ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer[] serializers, System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] baseCtorCallbacks, bool isRootType, bool useConstructor, ProtoBuf.Meta.CallbackSet callbacks, System.Type constructType) Line 43   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer() Line 283 + 0xe3 bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.Serializer.get() Line 209 + 0x11 bytes  C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter dest) Line 357 + 0x51 bytes   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(object value, int key, ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter writer, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle style, int fieldNumber) Line 101 + 0x45 bytes    C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(System.IO.Stream dest, object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle style, int fieldNumber, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) Line 467 + 0x24 bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(System.IO.Stream dest, object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle style, int fieldNumber) Line 435 + 0x32 bytes    C#
```

I am using rev 424.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I do not understand anything. It does not work if I make `Base<T>` a non generic type as well. I must be missing something really basic here.

**EDIT2**

Debugging the code reveals that field numbers of the base type properties are collected in the same list with the field numbers of the derived types. From that I deduce that the only way for the inheritance to work is with surrogates. At least in revision 424.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.AddSubType(1, typeof(FlowFolder));` vs `[DataMember(Order = 1)]`

The field-number used to identify a sub-type must not conflict with any defined fields on that same type. Just *use a number that doesn't conflict*. The conflict only applies to *that type* - it doesn't have to be unique among the sub-types; for example, `.AddSubType(8, typeof(FlowFolder));` would be fine, and it would not matter whether `FlowFolder` had a "field 8".

> From that I deduce that the only way for the inheritance to work is with surrogates.

I don't see how that follows....?

Comment: My bad, I thought I do not have to care about the sub type field numbers. Until now I only used inheritance with surrogates and no such problem exists there (because surrogate does not actually derive from the basee type). Anyway, thanks for clearing it.

Comment: This can be really hard to guess the number if you're using "RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InferTagFromNameDefault = true"

Comment: Why dont "RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InferTagFromNameDefault = true" also consider the Name from DataContract as the tag?

Comment: @IúridosAnjos - simply a pragmatic choice that is simple and predictable